# PHP reference mess, bad optimisation or intended behaviour?

Tags: php, reference

Please help me to understand whether this symptom is an unintended error / bad optimisation / or expectable behaviour in PHP.

Here is a little  code:

```
class Packet {
  public $length;
  public $time;
}

class Stream {
  public $packets = array();

  // Basically what I want is to make sure
  // I put my packet in the array as reference
  // because later in the code where I call this
  // function, I change my Packet object's values
  // and I want this change to appear in the
  // $this->packets array. So I pass by reference.
  // I don't want to copy the Packet object at all!
  public function addPacket(&$packet){
    $this->packets[] = &$packet; //note here the reference operator
  }
}

...

foreach($packets as $packet){
  $myPrettyStream->addPacket($packet);
}
```

So I explained in code comment what I want to do.
My problem is: after I add all the packets to my stream in the foreach, ALL my `Stream::packets` array elements will contain (the reference) to the LAST `$packet` I added to the stream.

Seems like PHP preserves the `$packet` variable inside my `addPacket(&$packet)` function between function calls. (which could be intended or bad optimisation?)
Whether or not I pass the `&$packet` variable by reference to the array ( basically a reference reference &&$packet) or simply the reference of `$packet` (&$packet), I don't think this should be the expected behaviour.

It works though, if I don't make a reference inside the function:

```
public function addPacket(&$packet){
  $this->packets[] = $packet;
}
```

Please someone explain why this behaviour makes sense!

Thanks!

=========================================================================

**Solution**

Thanks for the right answer I emulated a function call which just behaves the same:

```
// try to emulate function call inside iteration
$packet         = $packets[0];                 
$functionPacket = &$packet;            
$packetsItem[0] = &$functionPacket; //functionpacket holds a reference to $packet
var_dump($packetsItem);

echo "\nsecond iteration\n";
unset($functionPacket);
$packet         = $packets[1];                 
$functionPacket = &$packet;            
$packetsItem[1] = &$functionPacket;
var_dump($packetsItem);

output:
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  &object(Packet)#1 (2) {
    ["time"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  &object(Packet)#2 (2) {
    ["time"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  &object(Packet)#2 (2) {
    ["time"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP always pass objects by-reference, thus there is absolutely no need for `&` and in your case it's even harmful (as you already realized ;)).

The problem is, that you "reference the reference" and not the object. This means, that every item in your array is a reference to `$packet` from inside the method, that is itself a reference to `$packet` from *outside* the array. Now when you change `$packet` (the `foreach`-loop) it seems, that every item in the array changes, but in fact they remain the same references as before.

As a rule of thumb: If you need `&` for everything else than `out`-arguments, you should think about your design. If you *require* `out`-arguments then you should think about it too. Usually there is no need for this (anymore) and it makes many things (unnecessary) complicated. And especially: Never use `&` for micro-optimizations.

You can imagine, that it looks like this (even if its maybe not that accurate)

```
// First iteration
$packet --> $packets[0]
// Pass to method
Stream::addPackage():$packet --> $packet --> $packets[0]
// Assign to array
Stream::$packets[0] --> Stream::addPackage():$packet --> $packet --> $packets[0]

// Second iteration (!)
Stream::$packets[0] --> Stream::addPackage():$packet --> $packet --> $packets[1]
```

Note, how `Stream::$packets[0]` now "points" to `$packets[1]`

Comment: Hi, so "objects always are passed by reference" means I do not need reference operator in this case at all, right? I understand that from the array I duble reference to $packet from outside the function call. However it does not explain why the array elements refer to the same $packet inside the function. $packet inside the function behaves static.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting it. I was not at all aware of that I would reference to the outside `$packet` variable itself this way (which is reall just a reference to the object behind it). I update my question with an emulation of a function call, which behaves the same.

Comment: @illEatYourPuppies: Also read http://blog.golemon.com/2007/01/youre-being-lied-to.html.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if `$a = new Packet(1); $b = $a; $b->time = 8` would trigger a copy-on-write. But did not, since I did not assign a new value to $b but only changed a property of the same object.
PHP is very strange animal :D

Comment: No. Objects are _always_ passed as reference (since PHP5). And this is not a "feature" of PHP: At least I don't know _any_ language, were an object gets copied every it is passed to a function/method.

Comment: got it! I'm not a newbie of php, but sometimes these little problems reveal misunderstanding in details of concept or in other viewpoint unused knowledge needs to be refreshed sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

When you pass a variable by reference, you only need to add the & in the function declaration.  Within the function you don't need to add the & in front of the variable name.

```
public function addPacket(&$packet){
    $this->packets[] = &$packet; //  should be $this->packets[] = $packet;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that was not my question. I want to know why PHP behave s as such when I do as what I explained.